# Loop saves png files wrongly?

Tags: r, for-loop, save, png

```
Models <- list.files(path = "D:/Final_Projections_Global", full.names = TRUE, pattern = ".asc$")
Models <- lapply(Models, raster)
Models_G <- raster::stack(Models)

world  <- readOGR(dsn = "C:/Users/DELL/OneDrive/Documents/",
                  layer = "World_Map_No_Antarctica")

cl <- colorRampPalette(c("#3E49BB","#3498DB", "yellow", "orange", "red", "darkred"))

Names <- c(names(Models_G))

for (i in 1:19) {
  
    plot(Models_G[[i]], col = cl(400))
  
    plot(world, add = TRUE)
  
     png(filename = paste0(Names[[i]], ".png"),
         units = "px",
         pointsize = 8,
         bg = "white",
         width = 1400, height = 913, 
         res =  300, 
         family = "Helvetica",
         dev.off()
         )
}
```

I have been trying to save 19 models as png files in my working directory. But, somehow the names are getting disorganized, and the final (19th) image is not getting saved properly. May I know the solution. Thanks

Comment: I think your statements are in the wrong order. You should open the graphics device with `png(...)`, then do the plotting, then close the device with `dev.off()`.

Comment: The device `png` is being closed *in*  the device `png`.

Comment: Thanks so much @Andrew Gustar and Rui Barradas

Answer (score 1):

As @Andrew Gustar commented, I needed to fix the ordering:

> Your statements are in the wrong order. You should open the graphics device with `png(...)`, then do the plotting, then close the device with `dev.off()`.